# Why variable values assigned using bind_result are null?

Tags: php

I am getting `id` using POST method and trying to retrieve values and binding result with `bind_result()`, but the values are returned null. I used the below code.

```
    <?php
 //getting the database connection
 require_once 'configuration.php';

 //an array to display response
 $response = array();
 if($_POST['id']){
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name,price,description FROM products WHERE id = ?");
     $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
     $stmt->fetch();
     $result = $stmt->execute();
     if($result == TRUE){
         $response['error'] = false;
         $response['message'] = "Retrieval Successful!";
         $stmt->store_result();
         $stmt->bind_result($name,$price,$description);
         $response['name'] = $name;
         $response['price'] = $price;
         $response['description'] = $description;
     } else{
         $response['error'] = true;
         $response['message'] = "Incorrect id";
     }
 } else{
      $response['error'] = true;
      $response['message'] = "Insufficient Parameters";
 }
 echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

The JSON response is as follows:

```
{"error":false,"message":"Retrieval Successful!","name":null,"price":null,"description":null}
```

Can anyone please tell me whats wrong in the code?

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde Sir I think I have posted my genuine query.

Comment: You still need to fetch the data `$stmt->fetch();` before it will return anything.

Comment: @NigelRen added `$stmt->fetch();` , still null values

Comment: @NigelRen just edited with the updated code

Comment: `$stmt->fetch();` should be called after `$stmt->bind_result`

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks, it now worked!

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find that id is stored as an integer in your table. Assuming this is the case you need to update your parameters.

```
 $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
```

Comment: just tried changing it, but not a luck, still there are null values

Answer (score 0):

Just to post the comments as an answer...

The original code didn't fetch the data at all, the modified code called fetch before the bind, you should have...

```
$stmt->bind_result($name,$price,$description);
$stmt->fetch();
```